# How can I connect the SearchBar to a different dataSource?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar

I have a View that has a searchBar and a corresponding TableView below it and I have it working correctly. My question is; is it possible to hook up the SearchBar to a different TableView ? I am new to swift and iOS development and can not find a way to get it done . This image will help illustrate . AS you can see I have a Search Table View Controller and it is working correctly with the Search Bar. **What I would like to do now is connect that SearchBar to the Second TableView instead** . I would like to do that because eventually i'll have a TableView that will not be connected to the SearchBar, however when a user clicks on the SearchBar a new TableView will cover the original TableView . Below I will show my code for the working TableView, again I would like to connect the SearchBar to the Second

```
  class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchBar.delegate = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    struct ApplicationData {
        var items: [String]
        var filteredItems: [String] = []

        init() {
            items = ["John","Sam","Oliver"]
            filterData(search: "")
        }

        mutating func filterData(search: String)
        {

                if search.characters.count>0 {
                filteredItems = items.filter({ (item) in
                    let value1 = item.lowercased()
                    let value2 = search.lowercased()
                    let valid = value1.hasPrefix(value2)
                    return valid


                })

           }
            filteredItems.sort(by: { (value1,value2) in value1 < value2 })
        }
    }
    var AppData = ApplicationData()

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String){
        if let text = searchBar.text {
            let search = text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
            AppData.filterData(search: search)
            tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return AppData.filteredItems.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ZipSearch", for: indexPath)
        let data = AppData.filteredItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = data
        return cell
    }

}
```

I am thinking that maybe the **tableView.reloadData()** piece of code is defaulting to the original tableView but any help would be greatly appreciated .

[image]

Comment: why two table view then?..just change dataSource of first tableview and reload data.

Comment: Because as soon as I finish this part I will use the TableView on Search Table View for data unrelated to the Search Bar . Then the Search bar to filter unrelated data . Essentially the original TableView will be a timeline consisting of different data and the SearchBar will have a TableView of on Profiles searches.